# つー事 as a sentence starter

Tags: words

What does it mean when people start sentences with つー事? Is it an abbreviation of something else?
Two examples of such are:

[つー事で。](http://ameblo.jp/kojima-takahiro/entry-11878442610.html)

[つー事は、](https://twitter.com/mcYoucan/status/486872553244205056)

Comment: Silly question but should the「 ー 」used above, and in the other examples from before, always be read as ひと？

Comment: @Tim, Slight difference:「 一 」 vs 「 ー 」. One is the number, the other is a sound artifice, for extending the last sound.

Comment: @istrasci, I thought about that, but that one actually has: 「っつー」 instead of just 「つー」... (and translates to って言) Does the same hold here?

Comment: This is not a complete duplicate. つーことは is colloquialism for ということは, which is often taught as set expression in itself, similar to つまり.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「つー」 is the common contracted form of 「という」 and furthermore, of 「っていう」.

In the order of formality, it is 「という」、「っていう」 and 「（っ）つー」.  Learners should know that among the three, 「（っ）つー」 borders on slang.  DO NOT use it with your teacher, boss, etc.

Needless to say, 「つー」 is pronounced exactly the same as 「つう」.  (That is only if you are pronouncing 「つう」 correctly in a single syllable.)

All of these forms are quotative in function and meaning, referring to what has already been discussed, implied or has been shared as common knowledge between the speaker and the listener.

> 「つーことで」 means "and so", "therefore", etc. when it comes at the beginning of a sentence.  It is also sometimes used in colloquial speech as a conversation-ending phrase meaning "That is all I have to say."  In that case, it is said just before saying good-bye.
>
> 「つーことは」 comes at the beginning of a sentence and it means "So, that means ~~" or "If that is the case".

Comment: 関西では「ちゅーことは」って言います。関西人はチューが好きだからで（（ry